# Why ssh-agent group ownership is not root

Tags: permissions, security, ssh-agent, setgid

Trying to understand why ssh-agent has sgid bit and found this post [ssh-agent has sgid](https://serverfault.com/questions/290920/why-does-ssh-agent-have-sgid-set)

I have another question, why the group ownership of ssh-agent is nobody not root? What is the reason behind it? Will it still work if group ownership is root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were setgid root then the agent would run as group `root`, which likely has broader permissions than the user it started as. That could be a security risk; at the least, **running something as root unnecessarily is a red flag** (even the group) and requires extra attentiveness.

Setting the group ownership to `nobody`, which is a group that shouldn't have any meaningful permissions or files attached, means that **`ssh-agent` doesn't get any more rights than the user started with**. As the linked question says, the reason it's setgid in the first place is to prevent ptracing the program, rather than because it actually needs different permissions. In the [discussion thread linked from the other question](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.ssh/59), one of the developers notes:

> it would seem that the group is of no
>   consequence. It's the fact that the binary is setgid anygroup that's
>   important.

`nobody` is a handy group to use when you only want a side effect of setgid, not the behaviour itself.

I imagine it would still work with setgid root. I just tried that here, and it didn't complain at all and seemed to work in cursory testing. That said, I can't think of any actual reason to change it to that - everyone seems to be better off with it running as group `nobody` than group `root`.

I don't suggest changing the permissions of files installed by your package manager, in any case, because they tend to get upset about any modifications to the files they control.

Comment: +1. More programs setuid/setgid root means more entry points on the machine (and everything connected to it) (Each bug, weak security, etc in the program's code could maybe be exploited to create/run things as root. Whereas setuid/setgid nobody wouldn't give exploits much access, other than basic unpriviledged commands use and file creation).

Answer (score 4):

The point of making `ssh-agent` setgid is to increase security by making the process impossible to debug, so that even a process running as the same user can't dump keys from memory.

`ssh-agent` should not in fact have additional privileges. In case there is a vulnerability in `ssh-agent`, if it is setgid to some group, this confers the user the privileges of that group. Running `ssh-agent` setgid therefore increases the security risk… unless the group that `ssh-agent` runs as has in fact no privileges whatsoever — in particular, no write permission on any file.

The best way to run a program setgid without having an impact on other programs is to use a dedicated group. That's what Debian does, for example: `ssh-agent` runs as the group `ssh`. Fedora uses the group `nobody`, which is dodgier but still ok as no file should ever be owned by the group `nobody`. The group `root` would be a bad idea because it owns a lot of files.

Comment: +1(00) for those important additionnal infos! (for why setgid prevents same user to debug: Gilles himself comes up in a google search : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15912/27616 )